# Getting `undefined` when using ng-repeat and radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am encountering a strange behavior when using Angular's `ng-repeat` on a Bootstrap UI modal.

I have this dummy method in my `customerService.js` factory:

```
app.factory('customerService', [ function() {
    customerFactory.getCustomers = 
     function () {
        return [{ "name": "Terry Tibbs" }, 
                { "name": "Bobby Halls" }, 
                { "name": "Garry Brisket" }]
    };
    return customerFactory;     
}]);
```

This the `customerSelectionModal.html` modal template:

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Select a customer</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
            <input name="customer" type="radio" value="{{cust}}" ng-model="$parent.selected.item" />{{cust.name}}
        </label>
        <div ng-show="selected">You have selected: {{ selected }}</div>
        <div ng-show="selected">name: {{ selected.item.name }}</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the `customerController.js` file:

```
'use strict';

appModule.controller('customerController',
    ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', 'customerService', function ($scope, $modal, $log, customerService) {

        $scope.customers = customerService.getCustomers();

        $scope.selectCustomer = function () {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: paths.templates + 'customerSelectionModal.html',
                controller: 'modalInstanceController',
                resolve: {
                    customers: function () {
                        return $scope.customers;
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                $scope.customerName = selectedItem.name;
            }, function () {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };

    }]);
```

Finally the `modalInstanceController.js` controller for the modal form:

```
app.controller('modalInstanceController',
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, customers) {

        $scope.customers = customers;

        $scope.selected = {
            item: $scope.customers[0]
        };

        $scope.ok = function () {
            alert($scope.selected.item.name);

            $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    });
```

When the modal dialog is displayed initially I get `You have selected: {"item":{"name":"Terry Tibbs"}}` displayed correctly as this is the default customer 
selected by the `modalInstanceController` controller.  However, when I select a customer I get `You have selected: {"item":"{\"name\":\"Terry Tibbs\"}"}` and clicking the `OK` button just displays `undefined` in the alert
window and I don't know why.

The only possible clue is when a customer is selected the `name` property and it's value are escaped using a `\` for some odd reason that I haven't been able to figure out.

Has anyone any clue as to what's going on here?

Lastly, is it possible to set the radio button to the selected customer as it doesn't put a selection against the customer?

I am using the following:

AngularJS v1.3.9
Twitter Bootstrap v3.3.1
Angular UI Bootstrap v0.12.0

Comment: Why you use $parent in the radio button ng-model? Could you just use selected.item?

Comment: That's because an `ng-repeat` directive creates a child scope for each item so I need to use `$parent` to make it use the parent scope of the `ng-repeat` directive.

Comment: Ok, effectively I didn't remember it, sorry. Anyway, in the radio button, try to use `ng-value` instead `value` attribute.

Comment: I should have spotted that! You're right changing the code to use `ng-value` instead works great! Thank you!

Comment: Can I write the answer then? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyway, in the radio button, try to use `ng-value` instead `value` attribute.